# tableViewCell image to new view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

My image is not showing in my new view, it shows the url in my console but not on the simulator or device. I am getting the data from firebase and sending it to a class named User. The data then shows on my tableViewCell and I segue to a new ViewController, however the image view is blank.

//my code for tableViewController

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prefCell", for: indexPath) as! SFPTableViewCell

      let user = userList[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = userList[indexPath.row].name
    cell.location.text = userList[indexPath.row].location
    cell.bio.text = userList[indexPath.row].bio

    if let imageURL = user.image {

        cell.imageOne.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: imageURL)
    }

          return cell
}

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.destination as? SFProfileViewController{
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!.row
        destination.nameProfile = userList[selectedRow].name!
        destination.locationProfile = userList[selectedRow].location!
        destination.imageOneUrl = userList[selectedRow].image!

    }
        }
```

//my destination ViewController

```
class SFProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabelTwo: UILabel!

var user: User?
var userList = [User]()


@IBOutlet weak var imageOne: UIImageView!

var imageURL: String?

var imageOneUrl: String!

var nameProfile : String!

var locationProfile: String!

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(locationProfile)
    print(nameProfile)
    print(imageOneUrl)

    imageOne.image = UIImage(named: imageOneUrl)
    nameLabelTwo.text = String(describing: nameProfile!)
    nameLabel.text = String(describing: nameProfile!)

    locationLabel.text = String(describing: locationProfile!)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line  `destination.imageOneUrl = userList[selectedRow].image!` with

```
destination.imageOne = userList[selectedRow].image!
```

OR

Pass the image URL from tableViewCell to new Controller and then load the image from cache as you are doing in tableview delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Change below line and pass imageOne Url instead of image

```
imageOne.image = UIImage(named: imageOneUrl)
```

To

```
imageOne.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: imageURL)
```

As imageoneurl is url not image name

Comment: Same as I have answered you might wanna upvote the answer ! instead of giving a new one !!